# How to let a modal dialog block one widget and not all?

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog

I have a QWidget that has a vertical Layout consisting of a QWebView and a VirtualKeyboard widget. I have a slot  connected to the authenticationRequired signal of the networkaccessmanager retrieved from the webView.
In this slot i open a modal dialog to retrieve user credentials if authentication is required. 
But this blocks not only the webView but also the VirtualKeyboard. I read about setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal) but that does not help. Is it even possible to have a dialog block one widget but not the other?

## Constructor and Slot from Panel Class

```
Panel::Panel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
  verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

  QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);

  webView = new QWebView(this);
  //webView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
  webView->setLocale(QLocale::English);
  //webView->load(*url);
  webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
  webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows,true);
  keyboard = new QVirtualKeyboard(this);
  keyboard->setKeyboardLayout(0);
  keyboard->setMaximumHeight(100);
  keyboard->show();

  verticalLayout->addWidget(webView);
  verticalLayout->addWidget(keyboard);

  connect(webView->page()->networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),this,SLOT(handleAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)));
}

void Panel::handleAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply* reply,QAuthenticator* authenticator)
{
    LoginDialog *log = new LoginDialog(this);

    connect(log, SIGNAL(acceptLogin(QString&,QString&,int&)),this,SLOT(slotAcceptUserLogin(QString&,QString&)));
    log->show();
    //delete log;

    authenticator->setUser(username);
    authenticator->setPassword(password);

    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    webView->reload();
}
```

## Constructor from LoginDialog Class

```
LoginDialog::LoginDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    setUpGUI();
    setWindowTitle( tr("User Login") );
    //setModal( true );
    setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
}
```

Comment: I don't know enough about Qt to know if there are special features of Qt that allow you to do this with a "modal" dialog, but in general modals are not useful once you require *any* non-modal behavior.  In that case you have to implement a modeless dialog and manage the "enabled" state of other widgets within your own code.

Comment: Are the keyboard and the webview children of the same window? Modality will only work on window level, not on separate widgets inside them

Comment: Ah I see. Both widgets are children of the same window. So I think i have to try something else.

Comment: From Qt Docs for windows modality flag Qt::WindowModal : The window is modal to a single window hierarchy and blocks input to its parent window, all grandparent windows, and all siblings of its parent and grandparent windows.
So, you need to try to put your keyboard in another windows hierarchy or to be not in siblings, parent, grandparent of your others windows.